# Importing function from different file in Angular

Tags: angular, loops, for-loop

I created a custom snackbar component with a progress bar. I would like to add some functionality to make the progress bar load. My function works in the ngOnInit() of the component but does not work if the function is imported from a utils file. Can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

snackbar.component.html

```
<div class="snack-bar-container">
 <div class="snack-bar-row">
  <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="loadingVal"></mat-progress-bar> 
  <span class="snack-bar-message">This is a snackbar</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

My loop works if the function is directly in snackbar.component.ts

```
export class SnackbarComponent implements OnInit {
loadingVal: number = 1;

ngOnInit(): void {
 for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  window.setTimeOut(() => (this.loadingVal +=5), i * 100); // this works 
  }
 }
}
```

If I create a utils file with this function then import it in snackbar.component.ts, it no longer works...

snackbarUtils.ts

```
export function loadingProgress(loadingVal: number) {
 for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  window.setTimeout(() => (loadingVal += 5), i * 100); 
 }
}
```

snackbar.component.ts

```
import {loadingProgress} from "../snackbarUtils";

export class SnackbarComponent implements OnInit {
 loadingVal: number = 1;

 ngOnInit(): void {
  loadingProgress(this.loadingVal); // why is my function no longer executing here?
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem:

You don't need to use `window.xxxx`. You can just call `setTimeout` directly.

Also the reason why your `loadingVal` doesn't get updated is because when you put the `loadingProgress` in the `util` file, you lose access to the `loadingVal` in the `ExampleComponent`.

In the `setTimeout` function of the `util` file, the local `loadingVal` get increment by 5 everytime, but never get passed back to the original `loadingVal` in the `ExampleComponent`.

### Solution:

In order to increment the `ExampleComponent`'s `loadingVal`, we need to create a function and pass it to the `loadingProgress` as a callback. Everytime the `setTimeout` function run, will it call this callback.

This callback function `increaseLoadingValue` has the job to increase `loadingVal` by 5 everytime it's called.

##### util.ts

```js
export function loadingProgress(increaseValue: () => void) {

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    setTimeout(() => {

      // The callback function passed in from ExampleComponent.
      increaseValue();

    }, i * 100);
  }
}
```

##### example.component.ts

```js
...
import { loadingProgress } from './util';


@Component({
 ...
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit  {

  loadingVal: number = 1;

  ngOnInit() {
    loadingProgress(this.increaseLoadingValue);
  }


  // This function is used as a callback function.
  increaseLoadingValue = () => {
    this.loadingVal += 5;
    console.log(this.loadingVal);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I get the same results whether I use ```window.xxx``` or not. I can see the changes in the console but the UI is not updating as expected

Comment: @itsverde You said "why is my function no longer executing here?". The previous answer made it execute. Anyway, I updated my answer so now the UI also work.